# Flexmonster showing abrupt case-sensitive for columns

Tags: javascript, html

If two columns have same values but with different casing i.e first with lowercase and second with uppercase, then flex monster is showing first casing for both of the values. 
I have two country data with descriptions having same value but different casing. What flexmonster does, it takes casing of first column and populate in other columns. In this case DESCRIPTION with uppercase on all the description fields.

```
 new Flexmonster({
  container: "#pivot-container",
  componentFolder: "https://cdn.flexmonster.com/",
  report: {
    dataSource: {
  dataSourceType: "json",
  data: [
  {Country:'USA',description:'discription'}, // description in small
  {Country:'India',description:'DISCRIPTION'}, // description in capital
  {Country:'BLA',description:'dIsCrIPtiOn'}, // description mixed
  ]
 },
 options: {
   grid: {
     type: "flat"
  },
   configuratorActive: false
 },
 slice: {
    columns: [{
     uniqueName: "Country"
  },
   {
     uniqueName: "description"
  }
  ]
  }
 },
  width: "100%",
  height: 370
});
```

My question is why does flexmonster.js does so?
And need solution how can I keep fields case insensitive ?

https://jsfiddle.net/9w76thxf/2/

Answer (score 0):

Since the 2.7.7 version (https://www.flexmonster.com/release-notes/version-2-7-7/), Flexmonster has a property in the options object for distinguishing members with different cases: **caseSensitiveMembers**

The **caseSensitiveMembers** property needs to be specified in the options object the following way (please see https://www.flexmonster.com/question/string-auto-formatting-seems-to-be-applied-to-all-items-in-a-single-column/ for reference):

```
options: {
   caseSensitiveMembers: true
}
```

Here is a modified version of the JSFiddle example for illustration: https://jsfiddle.net/flexmonster/0ut6rxLe/

Hope this helps :)